NGINX: Is it possible to use $remote_user to match a location block
Context: I'm trying to enable disjoint sets of users accesses to specific subdirectories without having to:

Create a http_auth file with duplicate users (Realm approach)
Create multiple http_auth files (also, logically, with duplicate users)
Proxying to another service to perform the check

For example, one might have a file system layout thus:

/user_one/ - accessible to user 1 and admin
/user_two/ - accessible to user 2 and admin
/common/ - accessible to all users
/admin/ - solely accessible to admin

As a first step I am just trying to get the user-per-folder part working, without having separate htpasswd files for each location.
The attempt I have had so far is (inside a server block):
    location = /$remote_user/ {
        root /srv/valon-cs-dev;
        index index.html;
        add_header 'sent-user' '$remote_user';
    }

    location / {
        root /path/to/root;
        index index.html;
        return 404;
    }

However, the first location block never seems to match. I always wind up with the 404 error.
Somewhat maddeningly, if I set the second block to not 404, and have it set a custom header:
    location / {
        root /srv/valon-cs-dev;
        index index.html;
        add_header 'sent-user' '$remote_user';
    }

It also shows the $remote_user variable correctly set to the user.
I'm aware that nginx can be extremely finicky about variables and per-request-ness, but I've not found any clear documentation.

Is there something obvious I've missed in my config?
is there an alternative approach I should be considering?
Is this kind of thing even sensibly possible with nginx?


An alternate approach when you need the same set of directives in multiple places and don’t want to endlessly duplicate them is to place those directives in a separate configuration file snippet and load that where needed with the include directive.

@HBruijn - yes, but htpasswd files aren't subject to that logic; because you can't have multiple http file clauses inside a location block. So unfortunately that approach doesn't work.

It's not clear whether you want all authorized users to access one folder, you you want them to have separate folders and allow access only to that folder? Could you provide filesystem layout, possible requests and their outcome?

@AlexeyTen - updated with more information which I hope makes clear my intention.

I guess you'll have to implement it in lua/njs/some other backend. All auth check are executed simultaneously so you cannot check $remote_user in something like auth_request.

@AlexeyTen - in the absence of other answers, I agree that seems to be correct. If you post that as an answer I will accept it.
